# Bootstrap datepicker is not working with multiple inputs of same class or name

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I have the following inputs having the same name and same class:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control date-field" name="purchase-date[]"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control date-field" name="purchase-date[]"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control date-field" name="purchase-date[]"/>
```

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=yyyy-mm-dd&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&autoclose=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#) for these inputs.

I have tried following this jQuery code:

```
$('input[name="purchase-date[]"]').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  autoclose: true
});
```

and

```
$('input[class="date-field"]').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  autoclose: true
});
```

Only the first textbox shows datepicker, and the other two do not show any datepicker. Any workaround for this? I want the other two inputs to also show datepicker.

Comment: Have you tried using the class selector ?

$(".date-field").datepicker({...});

Comment: Unable to replicate. The example works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fur1apg3/. If you're dynamically appending the additional `input` elements to the DOM then you'll need to re-initialise the `datepicker()` on them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan- Yes, first input is already on page and rest other inputs are creating dynamically on page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan- Your hint for dynamic elements was a great help for me. Awesome.